# Tic-tac-toe program :Having trouble with looking for the winner by checking each row. What's the problem with my while loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

The program only asks for players' input for row and column five times, then it stops. But the program is still running, it just froze. I know there is some problem with my while loop but not sure what exactly causes the program run into error.

(I know a debugger would be helpful, but haven't yet figured out how to set up one in Visual Code. If you know any great guidelines for setting up C++ debugger, please let me know.)

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    const int ROWS = 3;
    const int COLS = 3;
    const char *values[ROWS][COLS] = { {"*A", "*A", "*A"} , {"*A", "*A", "*A"}, {"*A", "*A", "*A"}};;
    int player_iteration;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int counter_x;
    int counter_y;
    //ask the choose of player 1 and player 2 back and forth for a total of 9 times
    for (player_iteration = 0; player_iteration < 9; player_iteration++)
    {   
        //player 1
        if (player_iteration % 2 == 0)
        {
            cout << "Please enter Player 1's choose: row colum" << endl;
            cout << "row: " ;
            cin >> rows;
            
            cout << "colum: ";
            cin >> cols;
            
            //check for input validation
            while (rows < 0 || rows > 2 || cols < 0 || cols > 2)
            {
                cout << "Your input is invalid, try again!" << endl;
                cout << "row: " ;
                cin >> rows;
                
                cout << "colum: ";
                cin >> cols;
                
            }
            //Check if any duplication occurs
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < 1; i++)
            {
                if ( strcmp(values[rows][cols], "*O") == 0 ||  strcmp(values[rows][cols], "*X") == 0)
                {
                    cout << "Your input is duplicated, try again!" << endl;
                    cout << "row: " ;
                    cin >> rows;
                
                    cout << "colum: ";
                    cin >> cols;

                    break;
  
                }

                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
          
            }

            values[rows][cols] = "*O";
       
        }

        //player 2
        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter Player 2's choose: " << endl;
            cout << "row: " ;
            cin >> rows;

            cout << "colum: ";
            cin >> cols;

            while (rows < 0 || rows > 2 || cols < 0 || cols > 2)
            {
                cout << "Your input is invalid, try again!" << endl;
                cout << "row: " ;
                cin >> rows;
               
                cout << "colum: ";
                cin >> cols;
               
            }

            //Check if any duplication occurs
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < 1; i++)
            {
                if ( strcmp(values[rows][cols], "*O") == 0 ||  strcmp(values[rows][cols], "*X") == 0)
                {
                    cout << "Your input is duplicated, try again!" << endl;
                    cout << "row: " ;
                    cin >> rows;
                
                    cout << "colum: ";
                    cin >> cols;

                    break;
  
                }

                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
          
            }
   
            values[rows][cols] = "*X";

        }


        //check if the winner exists after the second round
        while ( player_iteration > 3)
        {   //check by row 
            for (counter_x = 0; counter_x < 3; counter_x++)
            {
                
                if(strcmp(values[counter_x][0], "*O") == 0)
                {
                    if (strcmp(values[counter_x][0], values[counter_x][1] ) == 0)
                    {
                        if (strcmp(values[counter_x][1], values[counter_x][2] ) == 0)
                        {
                            cout << "Player 1 won" << endl;
                            return 0;
                        }
                            
                
                    }
                }
                else if(strcmp(values[counter_x][0], "*X") == 0)
                {
                    if (strcmp(values[counter_x][0], values[counter_x][1] ) == 0)
                    {
                        if (strcmp(values[counter_x][1], values[counter_x][2] ) == 0)
                        {
                            cout << "Player 2 won" << endl;
                            return 0;
                        }
                            
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
        
            }

        }
          //check by column
            
        
    }

    
    
      
}
```

The output is right here

```
PS C:\Users\xueyi\Desktop\Sac_City\C C++> cd "c:\Users\xueyi\Desktop\Sac_City\C C++\" ; if ($?) { g++ tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp -o tempCodeRunnerFile } ; if ($?) { .\tempCodeRunnerFile }
Please enter Player 1's choose: row colum
row: 0
colum: 0
Please enter Player 2's choose: 
row: 1
colum: 0
Please enter Player 1's choose: row colum
row: 2
colum: 0
Please enter Player 2's choose: 
row: 1
colum: 1
Please enter Player 1's choose: row colum
row: 2
colum: 2
```

Comment: I think you just need to take the continue line out of the else statement. Right now it does not execute if either of your if statements returns true.

Comment: You can change your while to an if statement and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: @artie Yes! It works now. I have no idea why did I choose while instead of if...Thanks a lot buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in an infinite loop: your

```
while (player_iteration > 3)
```

never exits.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right.  I did not realize this. Thank you.